# WordPress moving post content/featured image to ACF flexible content field

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a new WordPress site and have to migrate the posts (100+) into the new build. I've imported the content via the WP Importer too.

I'm trying to find a way of migrating the content field of all posts (of a custom post type) into am ACF flexible content field nested in a repeater. Is there a quicker way of automating this instead of copying the content and pasting into the correct field in every single post.

For example, my fields are set up like so:
Section (repeater) > Module (flexible content) > One Column (WYSIWYG).

I have found this, but I can't get it working as it looks like this is just one nested field instead of two. https://www.nopio.com/blog/moving-content-from-default-wordpress-wysiwyg-to-custom-acf-field/

I'm also looking at migrating the Featured Image into an ACF field (not nested).

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

An edit, I've been trying to get the below code to work, but a little unsure of nesting through the fields.

```
$post = get_queried_object(); 
// get all posts

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'post_status' => 'any'
 );

 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
 foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
   // get post_content from default post WYSIWYG
   $default_field_content = get_post_field('post_content', (get_the_ID()));
   //flexible content
   $row = array(
     array(
       'section' => $default_field_content, // field name
       'acf_fc_layout' => 'section' // layout name
       ),
   );
  // flexible content field key value (have to use ‘inspect’ in ACF admin to get it
   $field_key = 'field_5b757ea595ae0';
  // update the field
   update_field( $field_key, $row, get_the_ID());
  
 endforeach;
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Why not just export these +100 posts using the built-in Import/Export tool, then import them into the new site the same way?

Comment: I've done that already. All of the content is in the_content field. But I need to move it into a nested field which is set up like Section (repeater) > Module (flexible content) > One Column (WYSIWYG). There's also the Featured Image (which is set) and I need to move this into a field called Image.

Comment: I have found this, but can't get it to work. 
https://www.nopio.com/blog/moving-content-from-default-wordpress-wysiwyg-to-custom-acf-field/

Answer (score 1):

The field key is the field key, nested or not. The thing to note is that the featured image is stored as an ID and the acf Image field is also stored as an attachment ID.

Do it stage by stage (and backup the database) to check.

I prefer to do these things as shortcodes.

I'll be along later to add the vital step of deleting the original Featured Image. (Done: be very careful that your first steps are correct because you can't do it after deleting the original Featured Image - obv.)

```
function migrate_logo()
{
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => '[POST TYPE]',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
  );

  $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();

    $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_ID();

    //Let's have a look
    echo $thumbnail_ID;
    echo '<br>';

    // field key value 
    $field_key = 'field_63f76a3a706da';
    // update the field
    update_field($field_key, $thumbnail_ID);
    // Check it
    echo "Field Value: ";
    the_field('logo');

    // Don't you just love Wordpress
    // Delete the original Featured image
    delete_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID());
    
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

}

add_shortcode( 'migrate-logo', 'migrate_logo' );
```